# why is Ricart-Agrawala algorithm deadlock free?

Tags: algorithm, distributed, deadlock

Can someone explain why this algorithm is free from deadlock specifically? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the need for release messages is removed (assuming all participants are correctly clock-synchronized and you also use timeouts to detect crashed participants).  Thank God for Wikipedia.